# Modify values based on condition in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe:

```
x   income

1   46200           
2   89345           
3   189982          
4   255465          
5   301189          
6   18100           
7   55234           
8   900672          
9   108221          
10  22201
```

I am attempting to apply a different function to each value depending on the range it lies within (e.g. 0-20k, 20-50k, 50-90k, 90-140k, & >140k). This function will look something like:

Average tax rate = ((Tax from prior marginal bracket + ((income - current bracket lower bound)*marginal rate))/income

I have attempted using a for loop with if & else if conditions however I'm having little success in applying this to my df, I'm not sure what my alternatives are in performing the required manipulation. I'm also unsure what R function would be best for such manipulation. Any help is greatly appreciated as R is new to me.

*edit*

[Tax schedule & prior taxable amounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJyLo.png)

Reproducible example:

Income = 60,000

Avgtax = ((6000 + ((60000 - 50000)*0.35))/60000

Avgtax = 15.83%

Comment: This example seems to be incomplete. Where are the tax values coming from? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We're missing the desired output in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward with the `dplyr` package. First, here's a bit of your sample data that we can work with as an example:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  income = c(46200, 89345, 189982, 255465, 301189, 60000)
)
df
```

**Output**:

```
  x income
1 1  46200
2 2  89345
3 3 189982
4 4 255465
5 5 301189
6 6  60000
```

Now, we can derive the other values we need and perform the final calculation:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    marginal_rate = case_when(
      income < 20000 ~ 0, 
      income >= 20000 & income < 50000 ~ .2,
      income >= 50000 & income < 90000 ~ .35,
      income >= 90000 & income < 140000 ~ .4,
      income >= 140000 ~ .5
    ), 
    prior_taxable_amount = case_when(
      income < 50000 ~ 0, 
      income >= 50000 & income < 90000 ~ 6000,
      income >= 90000 & income < 140000 ~ 20000,
      income >= 140000 ~ 40000
    ), 
    current_bracket_lower_bound = case_when(
      income < 20000 ~ 0, 
      income >= 20000 & income < 50000 ~ 20000,
      income >= 50000 & income < 90000 ~ 50000,
      income >= 90000 & income < 140000 ~ 90000,
      income >= 140000 ~ 140000
    ), 
    avgtax = 
      (prior_taxable_amount + 
      ((income - current_bracket_lower_bound) * 
          marginal_rate)) / income
  )
```

**Output**:

```
  x income marginal_rate prior_taxable_amount current_bracket_lower_bound    avgtax
1 1  46200          0.20                    0                       20000 0.1134199
2 2  89345          0.35                 6000                       50000 0.2212855
3 3 189982          0.50                40000                      140000 0.3420903
4 4 255465          0.50                40000                      140000 0.3825671
5 5 301189          0.50                40000                      140000 0.4003948
6 6  60000          0.35                 6000                       50000 0.1583333
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the data in a more friendly reproducible format with the specific example given added in as the last row

```
dd <- read.table(text="
x   income
1   46200           
2   89345           
3   189982          
4   255465          
5   301189          
6   18100           
7   55234           
8   900672          
9   108221          
10  22201
11  60000", header=T)
```

First, move your tax data out of an image and into a table

```
taxinfo <- read.table(text="
min max rate prior
0 20000 0 0
20000 50000 .2 0
50000 90000 .35 6000
90000 140000 .4 20000
140000 Inf .5 40000", header=TRUE)
```

Now we can more easily extract relevant info from this table using the row index for each bracket. We can easily find the bracket for each individual using `cut()`

```
dd$bracket <- cut(dd$income, breaks=c(-Inf, taxinfo$max),labels = FALSE)
```

We use the max values from the `taxinfo` table to create the breaks. We assign this value to a new column in the table. Now we know  the index for each bracket the person is in. We can use that info to index into the `taxinfo` table to do the calculation

```
dd$avgtax <- with(taxinfo, 
  (prior[dd$bracket] + (dd$income-min[dd$bracket])*rate[dd$bracket]) / dd$income
)
```

The values of `prior`, `min` and `rate` come from taxinfo. We use the bracket value to index into the columns for the values for each group. We assign this to a new column of the data as well. This is the output

```
    x income bracket     avgtax
1   1  46200       2 0.11341991
2   2  89345       3 0.22128547
3   3 189982       5 0.34209030
4   4 255465       5 0.38256708
5   5 301189       5 0.40039477
6   6  18100       1 0.00000000
7   7  55234       3 0.14179491
8   8 900672       5 0.46669154
9   9 108221       4 0.25215439
10 10  22201       2 0.01982794
11 11  60000       3 0.15833333
```

Comment: Thank you !!! Definitely a far more streamlined and logical approach than what i was attempting.